# Setting up spring email with application context

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jakarta-mail

I want my application to be able to send email on demand. I am currently using the tutorial from [www.mykong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/) which details setting up gmail settings.

However, I can't get the configuration settings into my annotated spring controllers: I want to avoid using the following:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(email-context.xml");
MailMail mm = (MailMail) context.getBean("mailMail");
mm.send(message);
```

From my investigation this seems rather frowned upon. I've tried several things, but none of them seem to find the correct bean and produce a nullpointerexception. Is there a way I can add this to any neccessary controllers, e.g. `@Property(mailMail)` or `@Autowired private mailMail`? Or should I just move the settings from my email-context into the java itself?

My files are below:

**EmailSender.java**

```
public class EmailSender {

@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

public void sendMail(String subject, String msg) {

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

    message.setFrom("beesden@*.com");
    message.setTo("beesden@*.com");
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(msg);
    mailSender.send(message);   
    }
}
```

**PageController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{name}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(@PathVariable("name") String name, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    logger.debug("Page request: " + name);      
    mm.sendMail("Hi","Test");       
    return "webpage";
}
```

**email-context.xml**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="toby@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="tobytobytoby" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
       <props>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
           </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailMail" class="org.system.EmailSender">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
```

*(note I changed the username and password for here, they are correct in the system...)*

Many thanks